# ¿Por qué no se realiza la Matriz Traspuesta? (Free Pascal)

Tags: array, revisión-de-código, pascal, freepascal

Estoy haciendo un programa para el que necesito un subprograma que me calcule la [matriz traspuesta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_transpuesta) de una matriz cualquiera. No entiendo qué parte del código esta mal. Compila pero me devuelve la misma matriz sin hacerle ningún cambio:

```
procedure Traspuesta (var tablero : TipoTablero);
var i,j:Integer;
    aux:TipoCelda;
begin 
  for i:=1 to MAXTablero do
    for j:=1 to MAXTablero do
    begin
      if (i<>j) then
      begin 
        aux:=tablero[i,j];
        tablero[i,j]:=tablero[j,i];
        tablero[j,i]:=aux;
     end;
   end;     
end;
```

Comment: Si comentas esta linea //tablero[j,i]:=aux; que resultado obtienes?

Comment: @Mariano se cerró porque las primeras versiones no contenían código (echa un vistazo al histórico de la pregunta)

Answer (score 1):

reemplaza

```
for j:=1 to MAXTablero do
```

por

```
for j:=1 to MAXTablero-i+1 do
```

ya que con tu cálculo estas obteniendo la transpuesta de la transpuesta((M^T)^T), es decir, la misma matriz

Answer (score 0):

En el planteamiento de tu pregunta dices que quieres transponer **cualquier matriz**, sin embargo tu ejemplo solamente trabaja con matrices cuadradas. He realizado este pequeño ejemplo que trabaja con **cualquier matriz rectangular**.

Antes, es importante notar que `pascal` no tiene realmente manera de declarar una matriz dinámica de más de una dimensión, aunque ciertamente puedes declarar una variable de tipo `array of array of`. Me baso en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5530752/255257) de **Andreas Rejbrand** en StackOverflow en Inglés para *construir* una matriz dinámica de 2 dimensiones.

Para probar el programa, el mismo construye una matriz de enteros de 2x4, la transpone y la imprime. Aunque el ejemplo está hecho con enteros, la idea funcionaría con cualquier tipo de dato. De hecho, en **delphi** u otro pascal con soporte para Generics, sería posible escribir una clase genérica que implemente el algoritmo y pueda instanciarse luego con elementos de cualquier tipo de dato.

Creo que el código habla por si solo, así que voy directo a él, si hace falta alguna aclaración, lo vemos en comentarios.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  T2DIntArray = array of array of Integer;


procedure ArrSetLength(var Arr: T2DIntArray; X, Y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Arr, X);
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    SetLength(Arr[I], Y);
end;

procedure PrintArray(const Arr: T2DIntArray);
var
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  Writeln;
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
  begin
    for J := Low(Arr[I]) to High(Arr[I]) do
      Write(Arr[I][J]:4);
    Writeln;
  end;
end;

procedure Transponer(const Arr: T2DIntArray; var ArrT: T2DIntArray);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Temp: Integer;
begin
  ArrSetLength(ArrT, Length(Arr[0]), Length(Arr));
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    for J := 0 to High(Arr[I]) do
    begin
      ArrT[J, I] := Arr[I, J];
    end;
end;

var
  X, XT: T2DIntArray;
begin
  try
    ArrSetLength(X, 2, 4);
    X[0][0] := 1;
    X[0][1] := 2;
    X[0][2] := 3;
    X[0][3] := 4;
    X[1][0] := 5;
    X[1][1] := 6;
    X[1][2] := 7;
    X[1][3] := 8;
    PrintArray(X);
    Transponer(X, XT);
    Writeln;
    PrintArray(XT);
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

La salida producida es esta:

```
   1   2   3   4
   5   6   7   8


   1   5
   2   6
   3   7
   4   8
```

## Edición: FreePascal compatible

Recién me doy cuenta que el código duplicado en mi respuesta original no compila con free-pascal, solo con Delphi. Acá dejo una versión que si compila con free-pascal:

```
program Project1;
uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TIntArray = array of Integer;
  T2DIntArray = array of TIntArray;

procedure ArrSetLength(var Arr: T2DIntArray; X, Y: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Arr, X);
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    SetLength(Arr[I], Y);
end;

procedure PrintArray(const Arr: T2DIntArray);
var
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  Writeln;
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
  begin
    for J := Low(Arr[I]) to High(Arr[I]) do
      Write(Arr[I][J]:4);
    Writeln;
  end;
end;

procedure Transponer(const Arr: T2DIntArray; var ArrT: T2DIntArray);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  Temp: Integer;
begin
  ArrSetLength(ArrT, Length(Arr[0]), Length(Arr));
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    for J := 0 to High(Arr[I]) do
    begin
      ArrT[J, I] := Arr[I, J];
    end;
end;

var
  X, XT: T2DIntArray;
begin
    ArrSetLength(X, 2, 4);
    X[0][0] := 1;
    X[0][1] := 2;
    X[0][2] := 3;
    X[0][3] := 4;
    X[1][0] := 5;
    X[1][1] := 6;
    X[1][2] := 7;
    X[1][3] := 8;
    PrintArray(X);
    Transponer(X, XT);
    Writeln;
    PrintArray(XT);
    Readln;
end.
```

Puedes darle una mirada a la ejecución en [ideone](http://ideone.com/IpDgUF)

Un saludo.